# How to intersect two queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, intersection

I have 3 tables in the database as follows:

```
airlines
+----+-----------------+-------+---------+ 
| Id | Name            | Abbr  | Country |
+----+-----------------+-------+---------+
| 1  | United Airlines | UAL   | USA     |
| 2  | US Airways      | USAir | USA     |
|... | ...             | ...   | ...     |
+----+-----------------+-------+---------+
```

```
airports
+--------------+------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| City         | Code | Name        | Country       | CAbbr |
+--------------+------+-------------+---------------+-------+
| Apalachicola | AAF  | Municipal   | United States | US    |
| Abilene      | ABI  | US Airways  | United States | US    |
| ...          | ...  | ...         | ...           | ...   |
+--------------+------+-------------+---------------+-------+
```

```
flights
+---------+----------+--------+-------------+
| Airline | FlightNo | Source | Destination |
+---------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 1       | 28       | APG    | ASY         |
| 1       | 44       | CVO    | ACV         |
| ...     | ...      | ...    | ...         |
+---------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

I am trying to report all pairs of airports served by both Frontier and JetBlue. Each airport pair must be reported exactly once (if a pair X,Y is reported, than a pair Y,X is redundant and should not be reported).

I believe I understand how to get the Frontier flights and JetBlue flights separately:

```
SELECT  ap1.Code, ap2.Code
FROM    flights f, airports ap1, airports ap2, airlines al
WHERE   ap1.Code = f.Source
AND     ap2.Code = f.Destination
AND     f.Airline = al.Id
AND     al.Abbr = 'Frontier'
ORDER BY ap1.Code ASC;

SELECT  ap1.Code, ap2.Code
FROM    flights f, airports ap1, airports ap2, airlines al
WHERE   ap1.Code = f.Source
AND     ap2.Code = f.Destination
AND     f.Airline = al.Id
AND     al.Abbr = 'JetBlue'
ORDER BY ap1.Code ASC;
```

But I don't understand how to get the Intersection between them. I've tried both LEFT JOIN and WHERE EXISTS but I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting what looks to be more of a Union than an Intersection. Here is my most recent attempt(definitely wrong).

```
SELECT  ap1.Code, ap2.Code AS code
FROM    airports ap1, airports ap2
WHERE 
EXISTS (SELECT  ap1.Code, ap2.Code
        FROM    flights f, airports ap1, airports ap2, airlines al
        WHERE   ap1.Code = f.Source
        AND     ap2.Code = f.Destination
        AND     f.Airline = al.Id
        AND     al.Abbr = 'Frontier') AND
EXISTS (SELECT  ap1.Code, ap2.Code
        FROM    flights f, airports ap1, airports ap2, airlines al
        WHERE   ap1.Code = f.Source
        AND     ap2.Code = f.Destination
        AND     f.Airline = al.Id
        AND     al.Abbr = 'JetBlue')
ORDER BY ap1.Code ASC;
```

And once the intersection is found I'm not quite sure how to go about making X,Y pairs and Y,X pairs distinct because DISTINCT wouldn't recognize the tuples as the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to put a "or" like this:
  `AND     (al.Abbr = 'Frontier' or al.Abbr = 'JetBlue')`
and then you can put a `group by id`.

Comment: You're showing implicit joins, but also mention LEFT JOIN, so it is worth noting that mixing implicit (comma) and explicity (JOIN) syntax usually doesn't work out well for people; and using implicit join notation is considered poor form and archaic (and has been for a decade or two).

Comment: @Uueerdo thank you for the reminder, I always make that mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you need both then you could try using IN for the airlines:

```
SELECT  ap1.Code, ap2.Code
FROM    flights f
INNER JOIN airports ap1 ON  ap1.Code = f.Source
INNER JOIN airports ap2 ON ap2.Code = f.Destination
INNER JOIN airlines al ON  f.Airline = al.Id
WHERE  al.Abbr IN ( 'Frontier', 'JetBlue')
ORDER BY ap1.Code ASC;
```

You should avoid old (1992) implicit join syntax based on where and use explicit join syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT apPairs.*, ap1.stuff, ap2.stuff
FROM (
   SELECT LEAST(f.Source, f.Destination) AS ap1Code
      , GREATEST(f.Source, f.Destination) AS ap2Code
   FROM airlines AS al
   INNER JOIN flights AS f ON al.Id = f.Airline
   WHERE al.Abbr IN ('Frontier', 'JetBlue')
   GROUP BY ap1Code, ap2Code
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT al.Abbr) = 2  -- Served by both airlines
) AS apPairs
INNER JOIN airports AS ap1 ON apPairs.ap1Code = ap1.Code
INNER JOIN airports AS ap2 ON apPairs.ap1Code = ap2.Code
;
```

I used LEAST and GREATEST to merge any (X,Y) and (Y,X) redundancies; those functions are MySQL specific though, so in other RDBMS you may need to create your own versions of those. *Note: depending on how this data is being used, you may want to double-check the assumption that x->y and y->x pairs are really redundant; it is possible (at least in reality) that an airline could have an X->Y->Z->X route, but no direct Y->X.*

COUNT(DISTINCT) in the HAVING clause makes sure to only count each airline abbreviation only once, so 100 flights will not inflate the numbers. It's use in the query makes sure you get airports served by *both* airlines, rather than 
*either* airline.

Since the query in apPairs already has the codes, you don't even need to do the outer query; but I added in case you need information from airports table that you didn't not feel the need to specify in the question.